# Spring @Cacheable @EntityGraph not caching children

Tags: spring-cache

I have a JpaRepository with a custom method to find an object by ID and load children with an entity graph, e.g.

```
@EntityGraph(value="Parent.children",  type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
public Parent findByIdAndLoadChildren(Long id);
```

I want to cache the query using @Cacheable.  The problem is that it won't cache the children.  Any suggestion on how I can get Spring to cache the children?

Comment: I'd actually avoid using `@Cacheable` with an ORM actually. A second level cache infrastructure actually manage a tons of things such as relationships, detached state and what not. Is there any reason why you don't configure 2nd level cache in your orm? (Hibernate, I believe).

Comment: I'll probably have to go down that road. They don't seem to play nice together.